# テーブルに紐づく属性が一致する数を数えたい

Tags: sql

説明がしにくいため先に例を記載します。

table_a

```
id
a
b
c
d
```

table_b

```
a_id    c1  c2
a   x   1
a   y   2
b   x   1
b   y   2
c   x   1
c   y   2
c   z   3
d   x   1
d   y   3
```

欲しい結果

```
id  count
a   2
b   2
c   1
d   1
```

table_b内でa_id毎にc1とc2がありますが、これらが完全に一致するレコードをカウントしたいです。（idがaの場合、table_bには2レコードあるので、その2レコードのc1がxでc2が1, c1がyでc2が2の2つのレコードが完全に一致するidをカウントしたい。）
（例だと自分も含んでa（自分）とbが一致するので2としていますが、含まなくても良いです）

※データベースはredshiftですので、DB依存がない一般的なSQLで実現できると助かります。
※実際にはtable_aにはかなりの数のレコードが含まれます。
※table_bで、a_idに紐づくレコードも最大100以上存在します。
※table_bのa_idとc1ではユニークになりません。（a_id, c1, c2でユニークになります）
※table_aにあり、table_bのa_idに含まれない場合にはcountは含まれる必要はありません。（含まれても良いです。）

どのような情報でも助かりますのでお願い致します。

Comment: `table_b`で(`a_id`,`c1`)が同じ行は複数存在しないと仮定できますか? `table_b`に出現しない`a_id`がありますか? あった場合、欲しい結果にcountを0としてその行が含まれるべきでしょうか

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。複数存在します。また、countは0で含まれなくても良いです。（後で本文に追記します。

Comment: c / x / 1、c / y / 2 の２行が存在すると思うのですが、欲しい結果は c / 1 なのでしょうか？

Comment: cは、x / 1、y / 2、z / 3の3つがあるため、この3つが一致するIDをカウントしたいのです。（質問文内で完全に一致と記載したのはこの意味です。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`ごとのレコード数をまず計算しておき、2つの`id`間で`c1`,`c2`が同じレコード数を両者のレコード数と比較してはどうでしょうか。

```sql
WITH n AS (SELECT a_id,count(*) FROM table_b GROUP BY a_id)
SELECT id1 id, count(id2)
FROM (SELECT b1.a_id id1, b2.a_id id2
      FROM table_b b1
      JOIN table_b b2
        ON b1.c1=b2.c1 AND b1.c2=b2.c2
      JOIN n n1
        ON b1.a_id=n1.a_id
      JOIN n n2
        ON b2.a_id=n2.a_id
      WHERE n1.count=n2.count
      GROUP BY id1, id2, n1.count
      HAVING n1.count=count(*)) t
GROUP BY id1;
```